# Question on Curvature of Vector Valued Function

Tags: calculus

Let's say we're given:

$$r(t) = t\ \mathbf{i} + f(t)\ \mathbf{j}$$

We're asked to prove that the curvature can be represented by:

$$\kappa = \frac{|f''(t)|}{{(1 + f'(t)^2})^\frac{3}{2}} $$

We know that the formula for the curvature is:

$$\kappa = \frac{|r'(t) \times r''(t)|}{|r'(t)|^3} $$

So, we have to find the cross product of $r'(t)$ and $r''(t)$ then take its magnitude, and find $|r'(t)|^3$

$$r'(t) = \mathbf{i} + f'(t)\ \mathbf{j} \\ r''(t) = f''(t)\ \mathbf{j} \\ |r'(t)|^3 = {(1 + f'(t)^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$$

The place where I'm stuck is here:

$$|r'(t) \times r''(t)|$$

because what I end up getting is:

$$r'(t) \times r''(t) = f''(t)\ \mathbf{k}$$

and if I take the magnitude of that I get:

$$|r'(t) \times r''(t)| = \sqrt{f''(t)^2}$$

Where are we getting the $|f''(t)|$ from in the $\kappa$ we're given? I'm just kind of lost because I have no idea if this is meant as an absolute value or as a norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed we have that

$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x| \implies |r'(t) \times r''(t)| = \sqrt{\left[f''(t)\right]^2}=|f''(t)|$$